# Threads and Classes

Tags: ruby, multithreading, class

I am new to ruby. I created a class called Station like this:

```
class Station

  def initialize()
    @no_crates = 5
    while(true)
      sleep(1)
      @no_crates = Integer(@no_crates) + 1
    end
  end

  def get_no_crates()
    return @no_crates
  end
end
```

The variable @no_crates is supposed to increase as time passes so I want to run this classes in a separate thread. How can I do that and then call the get_no_crates() function from time to time to get the @no_crates?

I tried the following but ofcouse its not working

```
st =  Thread.new{ Station.new()}
while(true)
  sleep(1)
  puts st.get_no_crates()
end
```

Comment: why am I getting so many down votes ??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this and just try to understand what you were doing wrong.

```
class Station

  def initialize()
    @no_crates = 5
  end

  def run
    while(true)
      sleep(1)
      @no_crates = Integer(@no_crates) + 1
    end
  end

  def get_no_crates()
    return @no_crates
  end
end


station = Station.new
st =  Thread.new{ station.run }
while(true)
  sleep(1)
  puts station.get_no_crates()
end
```

Here is a better looking version

```
class Station

  attr_reader :no_crates

  def initialize
    @no_crates = 5
  end

  def run
    loop do
      sleep 1
      @no_crates = @no_crates + 1
    end
  end
end

station = Station.new
st =  Thread.new{ station.run }
loop do
  sleep 1 
  puts station.no_crates
end
```

Comment: JazakAllah Khair again for the better version